# Image picker plugin crashes on Android

Tags: android

Stack trace:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper;
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils.canSafelyMutateDrawable(DrawableUtils.java:149)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateEditTextBackground(TextInputLayout.java:905)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.drawableStateChanged(TextInputLayout.java:1431)
                                                                at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:17035)
                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14557)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2838)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4288)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4266)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1477)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4089)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4062)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1427)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2214)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:811)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)


       02-28 14:11:48.207 26146-26181/in.hyshoper D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=ProductActivity, _si=-2804525119558517571, timestamp=1519807308204, fatal=1}]
  02-28 14:11:48.218 26146-26181/in.hyshoper V/FA: Using measurement service
                02-28 14:11:48.218 26146-26181/in.hyshoper V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
02-28 14:11:48.497 26146-26146/in.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: in.hxxxx, PID: 26146
                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableWrapper;
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils.canSafelyMutateDrawable(DrawableUtils.java:149)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.updateEditTextBackground(TextInputLayout.java:905)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.drawableStateChanged(TextInputLayout.java:1431)
                                                                 at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:17035)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14557)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2838)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4351)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4288)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4266)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1477)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4089)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4062)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1427)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2214)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:811)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)

                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
                                                                at android.view.View
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the a support library. Possibly `com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0`. Try adding that to your build.gradle.